# Encode partialy of a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dataset

I want to encode a column of dataset in `LabelEncoder` and the others one in `MinMaxScaler`. But it remains a float64

```
BinEncoder = LabelEncoder()
scalar = MinMaxScaler()

dat = df.values
X = dat[0:500,0:5]
X[:,-1] = BinEncoder.fit_transform(X[:,-1])
X[:,0:4] = scalar.fit_transform(X[:,0:4])
print(X)
```

`print(X)` , returns :

```
[[0.35435163 1.         0.96428571 0.05465126 0.        ]
 [0.07876241 0.85714286 0.85714286 0.04695418 0.        ]
 [0.11814948 0.64285714 0.5        0.08307676 3.        ]
 ...
 [0.25025542 0.79166667 0.54285714 0.10023708 1.        ]
 [0.25029285 1.         1.         0.0569226  1.        ]
 [0.25025127 1.         0.82608696 0.06935726 0.        ]]
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('./EURUSD_DATAFRAME.csv')
BinEncoder = LabelEncoder()
scalar = MinMaxScaler()


dat = df.values
#print(df.head())

X = dat[0:500,0:5]
Y = dat[:,5]
X[:,4] = BinEncoder.fit_transform(X[:,4])
print(X[:,-1])
X[:,0:4] = scalar.fit_transform(X[:,0:4])
print(X[:,-1])
print(X)
Y=BinEncoder.fit_transform(Y)

X = X.reshape(100,5,5)
#print(X[0])
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? The functions worked as designed. Are you looking for dummy values from the LabelEncoder? Did you want the values to be a smaller data type (i.e., float32)?

Comment: I want to convert them to 'int'. I edit the question to clarify the issue

Comment: MinMaxScaler is never going to return an int unless there are only two values given. Are you looking to just have the label encoder as an int? Does astype accomplish what you need?

Comment: @EliotK I am only scaling  X[:,0:4] with MinMaxScalar and X[:,5]  is gonna be scaled in LabelEncoder. I used astype but it doesn't work because all of X are Float64 but the last index which is 1 or 0

Comment: Just to confirm: LabelEncoder does not return a binary value -- it returns numbers representing different categories.

That said, can you update the code above with how you used `astype` and what the result was?

Comment: @EliotK  'X[:,4] = X[:,4].astype('int')' it returns 'float64'.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below. I missed that you converted to a numpy array which does not allow each column to have it's own data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you converted your DataFrame object to a numpy array, you have to choose one data type for the whole array. If you want each column to have a different data type, you need to keep it as a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
BinEncoder = LabelEncoder()
scalar = MinMaxScaler()

X = df.loc[:500,'A':'D']
X['D'] = BinEncoder.fit_transform(X['D'])
X.loc[:,'A':'C'] = scalar.fit_transform(X.loc[:,'A':'C'])
print(X.dtypes)
```

Hope that helps.